# JDBC: db2: Updating record: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -805, SQLSTATE: 51002, SQLERRMC: NULLID.SYSLH203 0X5359534C564C3031

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I am updating a  table and after about 1000 records update, i am getting following exception.

before this exception, data is going fine.

```
iteration: I: 1338
Update Record=> inventoryId:115428 microcodelevel: 7.3.0.12 id: 9194 // it's the value which is being updated.
Dec 29, 2016 8:06:19 AM com.ibm.hscms.service.impl.InventoryDataTempServiceImpl processUpdateInventoryDataTemp
INFO: 0000020060218AFC   75NWFXA  2145  Firmware:No Change 115428:7.3.0.12
com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.SqlException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -805, SQLSTATE: 51002, SQLERRMC: NULLID.SYSLH203 0X5359534C564C3031
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.zc.e(zc.java:1606)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.db.p(db.java:634)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.db.h(db.java:152)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.db.a(db.java:43)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.r.a(r.java:30)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.sb.g(sb.java:152)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.zc.n(zc.java:1186)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.ad.db(ad.java:1761)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.ad.d(ad.java:2203)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.ad.V(ad.java:521)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.ad.executeUpdate(ad.java:504)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at com.ibm.hscms.dao.impl.InventoryDataTempDAOImpl.updateRecord(InventoryDataTempDAOImpl.java:39)
    at com.ibm.hscms.service.impl.InventoryDataTempServiceImpl.processUpdateInventoryDataTemp(InventoryDataTempServiceImpl.java:94)
    at com.ibm.hscms.ProcessETLTableMain.main(ProcessETLTableMain.java:24)
com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.SqlException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -805, SQLSTATE: 51002, SQLERRMC: NULLID.SYSLH203 0X5359534C564C3031
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.zc.e(zc.java:1606)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.db.p(db.java:634)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.db.h(db.java:152)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.db.a(db.java:43)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.r.a(r.java:30)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.sb.g(sb.java:152)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.zc.n(zc.java:1186)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.ad.db(ad.java:1761)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.ad.d(ad.java:2203)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.ad.V(ad.java:521)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.ad.executeUpdate(ad.java:504)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at com.ibm.hscms.dao.impl.InventoryDataTempDAOImpl.updateRecord(InventoryDataTempDAOImpl.java:39)
    at com.ibm.hscms.service.impl.InventoryDataTempServiceImpl.processUpdateInventoryDataTemp(InventoryDataTempServiceImpl.java:94)
    at com.ibm.hscms.ProcessETLTableMain.main(ProcessETLTableMain.java:24)
```

I can't understand, why this exception is occurring. Can you please help me on this.

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/codes/src/tpc/db2z_n.html - gotta love IBM.

Comment: still no idea, why i am getting this. can you plz guide me further

Comment: You're running out of cursors; see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21526209/db2-sqlcode-805-sqlstate-51002-sqlerrmc-nullid-syslh203-0x5359534c564c3031?rq=1

Comment: Show the code that is failing. Are you closing your statements when you are done with them?

Comment: it''s working now, i closed the prepare statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after closing the prepare statement, it was working fine.